# How can I use UDP socket to send a msg to many Nodes on different address and different port?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a client that have to send a json string to many nodes in a peer-to-peer network.

This client can't send json in an iterative way to all nodes, but it have to send json in broadcast. Each node has a different address and different port.

How can I do it in java, using UDP socket?

Comment: You use UDP multicast, if you can get the routers to cooperate, but there is no reason why they can't all use the same port.

Comment: I have different nodes in the network. I have a decentralized architecture where all nodes make the same task and when a node exits from the network he has to notifiy all other nodes in broadcast. The nodes can be on different port. How can I use UDP?